# Using "grep" to search for specific type of files in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to find a specific line in files that contains "Mutual_Values_23.0" in a directory that contains a lot of subdirectories. I know this line number is stored in a file which starts with "gnuout_mutual_....txt" (the ellipses part of the file name is the time stamp so that varies).

I wanted to know if there is a way to specify "grep" command to look into the subdirectories only for the files starting with "gnuout_mutual_....txt"

I have tried

```
grep -r "Mutual_Values_23.0" *
```

but that's taking a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following option of grep:

```
 --include=GLOB
 Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude).
```

And for the line number you should use the `-n` option.
From within the root of the folders you want to look into, you can use this final command:

```
grep -nr "Mutual_Values_23.0" --include="gnuout_mutual_*txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to search all sub-directories for the "gnuout...txt` file with the search string "Mutual_Values_23.0"

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name gnuout_mutual_\*.txt -type f -exec grep "Mutual_Values_23.0" {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can use the *globstar* option:

> `globstar`
>       If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will
>       match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
>       If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and
>       subdirectories match.

So you can use it like:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ grep "search_string" **/glob-pattern
```

or in the case of the OP:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ grep Mutual_Values_23.0 **/gnuout_mutual_*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep has the `--include GLOB` option where `GLOB` can be used to specify the file name pattern that you need to match.

```
grep -rn --include 'gnuout_mutual_*txt' 'Mutual_Values_23.0' .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

`$ find . -name "*Mutual_Values_23.0*"`

Note: Run this command in the directory where you want to search your set of files.

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` to search for files and pass results to grep.

```
find /directory_where_to_search/ -iname 'gnuout_mutual_*.txt' | xargs grep 'Mutual_Values_23.0' -sl
```